# Is this a general bug of osmnx's installation? cannot import "shapely.geos import TopologicalError"

Tags: python, import, shapely, osmnx

When I want to import osmnx, this error comes up. I created a new environment before and followed the standard installation process via conda.

[image]

Comment: 1, how *exactly* did you install it. 2, what versions of OSMnx and Shapely are you using here? Print their version numbers to see for sure.

Comment: 1) conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
    conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx 2) osmnx 1.0.1 and shapely 2.0 (those were installed with the command above, i thought)

Comment: You're using a years-old version of OSMnx and a brand new version of Shapely. They are incompatible. Only OSMnx >= 1.3 works with Shapely >= 2.0. Recreate your environment (and optionally explicitly specify osmnx=1.3.*) and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. But why does above mentioned install command use osmnx version 1.0.1 by default on my machine? I am super sorry for bothering you with this rookie mistake!

Comment: That would be a `conda` package question, but I don't have a good answer for you. Perhaps you had an old version of OSMnx cached and conda just used that when it did the install.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer for others searching for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a years-old version of OSMnx and a brand new version of Shapely. They are incompatible.

- OSMnx >= 1.3 works with Shapely >= 2.0, [see here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/v1.3.0/requirements.txt).
- OSMnx < 1.3 works with Shapely < 2.0, [see here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/v1.2.3/requirements.txt).

Recreate your environment (and optionally explicitly specify osmnx=1.3.*) and it'll work. Make sure you follow the documented [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) and honor the dependency versions specified in OSMnx's `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/918#issuecomment-1397471071